# Parameter numPartitions in Partitioner class

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, partitioner

Gurus!

Can anybody answer: where defined parameter numPartitions in Partitioner class(value of this paramen)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the number of reducers defined for your Map Reduce job

Comment: o, i thik so. But where i defined number of reducers in this example:http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html ?

Comment: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Job+Configuration - setNumReduceTasks(int)

Comment: Oh, thanks. But i don`t understand - how many reduces i will have, if i will not use this parameter in the my code? In the mapred-site.xml i found parameter mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum. But i didn`t found the same parameter for reduce ...

Comment: if you don't configure the parameter, and it's not configured in mapred-site.xml (`mapred.reduce.tasks`) then the default is 1.

Comment: I found: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred-default.html. So, if i not specify additional property, i will have only one reduce on Job. Example: i have 100 servers(datanode + tasktracker), i run MR job in default conf i will have 100 mapers (1 per node) and only one reducer per cluster. Is it correct? I'm sorry for alot amount foolish questions, but hadoop - revolution in the thinking

Comment: yes, ifi you don't specify the property, you'll get one reducer for the job. The number of mappers is dependant on a number of things (input files, block sizes, 'splittability', etc), not the number of nodes in your cluster

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that? [numPartition in partition class](http://search-hadoop.com/c/Hadoop:/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.java%7C%7CnumPartitions). I just used search [there](http://search-hadoop.com/?q=numPartitions).

```
* @param numPartitions the total number of partitions. (as integer)
* [...] The total number of partitions 
* is the same as the number of reduce tasks for the job.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Driver class you will mention the no of reducers required for the job. That count is called numPartion count.
Like:

```
job.setNumReduceTasks(4);
```